# How to push certain commits only to Heroku but not github

Tags: heroku, github, git-push

I am using a github repository that is public and deploy my app on Heroku. How do I only push commits to Heroku and not to github when I then push to origin again?

More specifically, I need to edit a .env file for Heroku that I do not want to publish on Github. I did a few commits on that file and pushed it to heroku via `git push heroku master`.

I do not want those commits to be pushed to github as well. Now when I make new commits and push it via `git push origin master`, are the previous commits (which were only ment for Heroku) pushed as well? If yes, how do I avoid this?

Answer (score 1):

A few things:

1) .env *probably* shouldn't be checked in. A common pattern is to create a .env.sample file with placeholder values, add .env to gitignore and instruct users to copy .env.sample to .env and populate the placeholder values for development.

2) Those sensitive values can be set in Heroku's environment on the CLI via `heroku config:set FOO=bar` and will be available to your app through: `ENV['FOO']`